# How to find anything that matches excluding a certain string?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to get a match but am having trouble with the syntax, below I am using python but it can be any language, i just need the correct regex syntax:

```
import re
p = re.compile('foo%22([^%22])*')

input = "foo%22somedata%2Bgoeshere%22testbarbaz"

result = re.findall(p, input)
```

I'm trying to extract "somedata%2Bgoeshere". Basically I want the stuff between the %22's. So the regex I tried (above) isn't working b/c that 'not' operator is saying 'not %', 'not 2', and 'not 2'...I want to say, get anything until you see "%22".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use positive lookahead:

```
>>> import re
>>> input = "foo%22somedata%2Bgoeshere%22testbarbaz"
>>> re.findall('foo%22.*?(?=%22)', input)
['foo%22somedata%2Bgoeshere']
```

Comment: @codecraig - Don't forget to accept an answer if it works for you.

Comment: @Justin Morgan -- I know, it told me I had to wait 6 minutes before accepting so I kept a tab open in my browser to remind me to come back (which I now have :)

Answer (score 4):

Why do you need a regex? Simply do a split on `%22`

```
>>> input.split("%22")
['foo', 'somedata%2Bgoeshere', 'testbarbaz']
```

the stuff you want are anything that is not the first and last element of the returned result. KISS

Comment: So I mentioned that my code snippet in the question was written in python but what I really need is just the correct regex. @phihag's answer works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my take

```
mo = re.search("%22(.*?)%22", input)
print mo.groups(1)
```

Important is that you limit the `.*` with `?`, so that it stops as soon as it can match the closing "%22".

Comment: +1: seems to be exactly what the OP was trying to achieve (I remember having the same problem myself before discovering `.*?`)